# What is happening in the background when a member variable is initialized within a class but not with the help of the constructor?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, initialization, member-variables

Could anyone explain me the following C# sample code?

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    private int x = 100;
    private int y;
    
    public MyTestClass
    {
        y = 200;
    }
}
```

I understand that when MyTestClass is instantiated, the constructor gets called and y is assigned the value 200. But what happens in case of x? When is 100 actually assigned to x? Should I imagine this as if x were in the constructor and got its initial value there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All member declarations are processed before the constructor is executed. That should be obvious because, otherwise, the fields wouldn't exist to be set in the constructor. If a field is initialised where it's declared, that assignment happens when the member is processed. That means that, in your case, `x` already has the value 100 when the constructor code is executed. You can think of initialised fields like that as being populated pretty much as `struct` fields are, which happens without an explicit constructor.

Comment: and when are member declarations processed? During the compilation time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in presented code it's like in a constructor. See IL code, generated by compiler:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit MyTestClass
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private int32 x
    .field private int32 y

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 28 (0x1c)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 100
        IL_0003: stfld int32 MyTestClass::x
        IL_0008: ldarg.0
        IL_0009: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_000e: nop
        IL_000f: nop
        IL_0010: ldarg.0
        IL_0011: ldc.i4 200
        IL_0016: stfld int32 MyTestClass::y
        IL_001b: ret
    } // end of method MyTestClass::.ctor

} // end of class MyTestClass
```

Comment: If you add parametrized constructor it would be same. But x will be assigned to 100 at first, then to parameter.